# method objectのエラーが出てしまいます

Tags: python

method object is not iterable と出てしまうのですが、どうすれば良いのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `()` が足りないですね。。。

Comment: どこに足りないのでしょうか。
よろしければご教示ください。

Comment: `df_good['index'].tolist` と `df_bad['index].tolist` です。単に `tolist` としてしまうと**メソッドの名前**になります。`tolist()` とすることでメソッドが実行されてリストが返ります。

Comment: 解決しました！
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

`()` が足りないのが原因だと思われます。具体的には `df_good['index'].tolist` と `df_bad['index].tolist` です。単に `tolist` としてしまうと**メソッドの名前**になります。

`tolist()` とすることでメソッドが実行されてリストが返ります。

---

*この投稿は @user39889 さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*